# PHP showing data

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am showing images which are stored in my DB.

See code below

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result41);   

for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result41); $i++)
{
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result41);
  $upload_id = $row ['upload_id'];
  $file = $row ['FILE_NAME'];
  echo"     
  <td>
    <a href='image.php?id=$upload_id&gallery=$id'><center>   
    <img src='uploads/$file' alt='$name Gallery' title='$name Album'  class='resize'>                       
  </td>";   
}

if ($i % 0 == 4) {
  echo '</tr>'; // it's time to move to next row
}
```

My question is, after showing 4 columns how do I move onto another row? (only 4 images per row)

I have `if ($i % 0 == 4)` in my script but doesn't seem to be working?

Thanks

Comment: [**mysql_*** function are deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php).

Comment: Seriously, don't use mysql_* anymore....

Comment: Yep I know this now... going to change but still need to know how to start a new row

Comment: If think, you should use `($i % 4 == 0) echo "<tr>";` and `($i % 4 == 3) echo "</tr>";`

Comment: @Servuc - Thanks where would I use these?

Comment: @Servuc - It still shows as one continuous row...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this :

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result41); $i++)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result41);
    $upload_id = $row ['upload_id'];
    $file = $row ['FILE_NAME'];
    if($i % 4 == 0) echo "<tr>";
    echo"     
    <td>
    <a href='image.php?id=$upload_id&gallery=$id'><center>   
    <img src='uploads/$file' alt='$name Gallery' title='$name Album'        class='resize'>                       
    </td>";
    if($i % 4 == 3) echo "</tr>"; 
}
```

And look at `PHP PDO` for your Mysql access into Google ;)

And start you loop (for) at 0 ?

Comment: The only problem with this is the final closing `</tr>` won't be output unless the number of rows is exactly divisible by 4

Comment: Yes ! So, before the loop : `$totalRow = mysql_num_rows($result41);` 

And change the loop by `for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalRow; $i++)`

And after the loop (outside) : `if($totalRow % 4 != 3) echo "</tr>";`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result41); 
$k = 1; 

for ($i = 1; $i <= mysql_num_rows($result41); $i++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result41);
    $upload_id = $row ['upload_id'];
    $file = $row ['FILE_NAME'];
    echo"     
    <td>
        <a href='image.php?id=$upload_id&gallery=$id'><center>   
        <img src='uploads/$file' alt='$name Gallery' title='$name Album'  class='resize'>                       
    </td>";
    if($k == 4){
        $k = 1
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    } else {
        $k++;
    }
}
```

The `$k` variable counts to 4 and resets every time.
While it resets, it also ends and creates a new row in the table.